# SQL JOIN query create duplication with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an issue with my SQL query, I try to join two tables, but as result have duplicated lines.

There is my database schema:

```
# messages
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :request

# requests
has_many :messages
belongs_to :expense
```

I have an polimorphic association between my expenses and requests tables.

And this my query:

```
Expense.
  joins('LEFT JOIN requests ON expenses.id = requests.integration_id').
  joins('LEFT JOIN messages ON requests.id = messages.request_id').
  where('expenses.id IN (?)', @expenses_id).
  select('DISTINCT messages.user_id AS user_id').
  group('messages.user_id, expenses.id')
```

I get all expenses duplicated when I try to joins `messages` table.

What happen?

EDIT:

With this query is same result:

```
Expense.
  joins('LEFT JOIN requests ON expenses.id = requests.integration_id').
  joins('LEFT JOIN messages ON requests.id = messages.request_id').
  where('expenses.id IN (?)', @expenses_id).
  select('DISTINCT messages.user_id AS user_id').
  group('messages.user_id')
```

EDIT 2:

When I try this:

```
Expense.
  joins('LEFT JOIN requests ON expenses.id = requests.integration_id').
  count(:id)
#=> 45
```

But when I join messages

```
Expense.
  joins('LEFT JOIN requests ON expenses.id = requests.integration_id').
  joins('LEFT JOIN messages ON requests.id = messages.request_id').
  count(:id)
#=> 93
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solve this issue, I needed adding specific select on my `JOIN`. Because, when I `JOIN` the `messages` table, I get many messages with same `request_id`.

```
SELECT messages.user_id, SUM(expenses.total_in_home_currency)
FROM expenses
INNER JOIN requests ON expenses.id = requests.integration_id
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT(messages.request_id), messages.user_id FROM messages) messages 
  ON requests.id = messages.request_id
WHERE expenses.id IN (76)
GROUP BY messages.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I know the problem:

Rail's ActiveRecord will translate the field result into the model's attributes, and ignore anything outside. So let's say you have model `A` with attribute `b, c, d`. And your join result is:

```
 | b | c | d | e | f |
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
```

Then you group by `b` and `e`

```
 | b | c | d | e | count(f) |
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1        |
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2        |
```

This will create 2 records since the query result returns 2 rows, but they are exactly the same when translate into model A (b = 1, c = 2, d = 3).

In your case, `message.user_id` is the field causing this.

Remove it from group clause will fix the problem, but I don't know for sure what do you want `message.user_id` to be used for.

Comment: I have try this query and is same result... (I have edit the post)

Comment: I think it should be `group('expenses.id')` instead

Comment: Yes, but i want group by user because my process need that for sum and count many expenses.

Comment: If you want to group by user, I suggest you do the joins from `Message` model instead of `Expense` model.

Comment: Same result with join from Message. But I have no duplicated result when i make count('DISTINCT expenses.id'). But when I sum I can't use DISTINCT.